Conditional Formating
can someone help me with this. In status column, I want to automatically update the status of the stock if it is In Stock, Low Stock, Need to reorder or No Stocks using conditional formatting. In stock for example the Minimum QTY in stock it 25 and the remaining stock is 24-18, and in Low Stock is 17-10, Need to Reorder is 9-1, No stocks is 0. Thank you so much


What software do you use? It almost looks like Excel, but that is not mentioned anywhere. The only tag you applied is "inventory-software". What formatting is available depends on your software and what it provides, and their manual and user documentation surely describes how to use it.

Hi, I'm sorry. I am using excel for this inventory.

IF function

The IF function allows you to make logical comparisons between a value and what you expect.

In J2 enter =IFS(I2=0; "No Stock"; I2<10; "Need to Reorder"; I2<18; "Low Stock"; I2 >=18; "In Stock")
Then expand it across rows the rows so each row receives the formula, adjusted to itself (drag cell-bottom-right handle down).
Side note: The linked support page uses comma , as the parameter separator. But in Microsoft 365 and LibreOffice Calc I had to use semicolon ; instead of comma , as the parameter separators.
In the cell content editor there should also be a button that guides you through formulas: 

Ah, you're right. I quickly dismissed it when I looked at it thinking it would combine the ifs and have two alternative values. It doesn't seem to include an else case though :/. - I adjusted the answer to use IFS instead of multiple IF.

Thank you much. It is a really big help.
